# EJB Standalone Deployment in JavaFx Client App

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, javafx

I  want deploy a Stateful EJB Bean in my standalone JavaFx Client without an application server. The EJB Class has a entitymanager reference and makes transactions against db. The Project is a maven archetype and i added the EJB class in a package.
From my main method i make a JNDI lookup like this

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(EJBContainer.APP_NAME, "testejb");
            props.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File("target/classes"));
            EJBContainer ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(props);
            Context ctx = ec.getContext();
            myEjbClass = (MyEjbClass) ctx.lookup("java:global/testejb/MyEjbClass");
```

I become exception javax.ejb.EJBException: No EJBContainer provider available: no provider names had been found. I have added the javaee-7 and glassfish-embedded-shell to my pom.xml.Why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured and started the embedded Glassfish in your program?

This can be done by doing this:

```
 BootstrapProperties bootstrapProperties = new BootstrapProperties();
 bootstrapProperties.setInstallRoot("C:\\applicationserverdir");    
 GlassFishRuntime glassfishRuntime = GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(bootstrapProperties);

 GlassFishProperties glassfishProperties = new GlassFishProperties();
 glassfishProperties.setInstanceRoot("C:\\applicationserverdir\\domains\\myJavaFXAppDomain");
 glassfishProperties.setPort("http-listener", 8080);
 glassfishProperties.setPort("https-listener", 8181);
 GlassFish glassfish = glassfishRuntime.newGlassFish(glassfishProperties);
 glassfish.start();
```

More information on setup embedded Glassfish here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2424/giijw.html#scrolltoc

Also, which Maven archetype are you using?